# Remove the last characters of a string

Tags: perl

How can I remove the last six characters of a string using Perl? In my case I need to remove `:00:00`

For example

```
goes_2017-05-14_00:00:00
```

to get

```
goes_2017-05-14_
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume the string is `$s`.

```
$s = substr $s, 0, -6;
```

Comment: ...@timrau thank you....another question... if the string is the name of a file, how can I save the new name? how can I change the name of the file in my folder? not only doing a print, also, I want to substr the character in the name of the file...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substr`:

```
substr($string, -6) = "";
# or
substr $string, -6, length $string, "";
```

Or a substitution:

```
$string =~ s/.{6}$//;
```

Or [chop](http://p3rl.org/chop):

```
chop $string for 1 .. 6;
```

Comment: Or `substr($string, -6) = "";`.